# What are the alternatives to the MultiSelectField library for Django 5?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-multiselectfield

```
ROLES = [
    ("admin", "Администратор"),
    ("user", "Пользователь"),
]

class Permission(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    roles = MultiSelectField(choices=ROLES)
```

I need to implement this functionality. However, the MultiSelectField library does not work with Django 5 version. To fix this, you need to remove _get_flatchoices from the fields.py file in the root of the library. However, when installing dependencies via requirements.txt when deploying to the server, this will not work. Help me please

I wanted to use ArrayField, but this is not suitable since the Sqlite database is used locally

Comment: See https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield/issues/142 and https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield/issues/141

Comment: Unfortunately this is not suitable

Comment: What is not suitable about installing the https://github.com/olivierdalang/django-multiselectfield fork?

Comment: This method did not work, since when going through pipelines, libraries are installed via pip install.
I found a way to solve my problem. I created a Libs folder in my project, where I added the corrected MultiSelectField library code. Now when using MultiSelectField I will import it from this libs Libs

Comment: You do know you can `pip install git+https://github.com/olivierdalang/django-multiselectfield.git`, right?

Comment: haven't used this before :)

Comment: Well, doing that might be a better alternative than the way you found (vendoring the external code into your app).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem. I created a Libs folder in my project, where I added the corrected MultiSelectField library code. Now when using MultiSelectField I will import it from this libs Libs